# How to read webpage dataset in pandas?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to read this table [image]
on the webpage: https://datahub.io/sports-data/german-bundesliga

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://datahub.io/sports-data/german-bundesliga"
pd.read_html(url)[2]
```

It reads another tables but not the tables of this type.

Also there is a link to this specific table:
https://datahub.io/sports-data/german-bundesliga/r/0.html

I also tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://datahub.io/sports-data/german-bundesliga/r/0.html"
pd.read_html(url)
```

But it says that there are no tables to read

Comment: Why not download the csv files and use ```pd.read_csv``` instead. They are available from the link you provided

Comment: Did the answer provide you with any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessity to use the HTML form of the table cause the table is available in CSV format.

```
pd.read_csv('https://datahub.io/sports-data/german-bundesliga/r/season-1819.csv').head()
```

output:

```
    Div     Date    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    FTHG    FTAG    FTR     HTHG    HTAG    HTR     ...     BbAv<2.5    BbAH    BbAHh   BbMxAHH     BbAvAHH     BbMxAHA     BbAvAHA     PSCH    PSCD    PSCA
0   D1  24/08/2018  Bayern Munich   Hoffenheim  3   1   H   1   0   H   ...     3.55    22  -2.00   1.92    1.87    2.05    1.99    1.23    7.15    14.10
1   D1  25/08/2018  Fortuna Dusseldorf  Augsburg    1   2   A   1   0   H   ...     1.76    20  0.00    1.80    1.76    2.17    2.11    2.74    3.33    2.78
2   D1  25/08/2018  Freiburg    Ein Frankfurt   0   2   A   0   1   A   ...     1.69    20  -0.25   2.02    1.99    1.92    1.88    2.52    3.30    3.07
3   D1  25/08/2018  Hertha  Nurnberg    1   0   H   1   0   H   ...     1.76    20  -0.25   1.78    1.74    2.21    2.14    1.79    3.61    5.21
4   D1  25/08/2018  M'gladbach  Leverkusen  2   0   H   0   0   D   ...     2.32    20  0.00    2.13    2.07    1.84    1.78    2.63    3.70    2.69

5 rows × 61 columns
```